# Duda asincronia JS , no esta sucediendo lo que espero

Tags: javascript, async-await, programacion-asincrona

```
const simulateAjax = {
  call : async ()=>{
    console.log('starting calling..');
    setTimeout( function(){
      console.log('finishing call..')
    },2000)
  }
};


await simulateAjax.call();
//La linea de abajo no deberia de estar ejecutandose hasta que 'finishing call...' salga por consola, pero no esta sucediendo lo esperado, por que ?
console.log('Program has been finished..');
```

Tengo ese codigo, el orden de log que yo espero es :

**1. 'starting calling..'** 
**2. 'finishing call..'** 
**3. 'Program has been finished..'**

Pero el que estoy obteniendo es :

**1. 'starting calling..'** 
**2. 'Program has been finished..'** 
**3. 'finishing call..'**

Answer (score 0):

Ya he visto lo que pasaba :

```
const simulateAjax = {
  call: async () => {
    console.log('starting calling..');

    // Envolver setTimeout en una promesa personalizada
    await new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('finishing call..');
        resolve(); // Resuelve la promesa cuando setTimeout se completa
      }, 2000);
    });
  }
};

// Utilizar await para esperar la finalización de simulateAjax.call()
await simulateAjax.call();

console.log('Program has been finished..');
```

**Destaco los siguiente cambios:** 
He encerrado el setTimeOut dentro de una promesa para que sea asincrono y luego le he puesto el await para hacerlo sincrono.
Una vez ha doy por terminada la promesa lo indico con el `resolve();` al final del mismo, asi deja continuar el flujo principal

Comment: Veo que chatGPT pudo ayudarte, quizás la próxima vez ahorres un tiempo consuladolo primero.

Comment: A mi me sigue saliendo el mismo output, con `2. 'Program has been finished..' `